# converting a data type varchar to numeric

Tags: java, mysql, sql

```
Statement stmt1 = null; 
ResultSet srs1 = null; 
List3 = new ArrayList<String>(); 
stmt1 = conn.createStatement(); 
srs1 = stmt1 .executeQuery("SELECT [FILE_ACL].[FILE_SYSTEM_ID],
                      [USER_LITE].[USERS].[SYS_ID] FROM [FILE_ACL],
                      [USER_LITE].[USERS] WHERE [FILE_ACL].[PEOPLE_SYSTEM_ID]
                     = 'u' AND [USER_LITE].[USERS].[SYS_ID] 
                     = [FILE_ACL].[PEOPLE_SYSTEM_ID]"); 

while (srs1.next()) { 
    List3.add(srs1.getString("FILE_SYSTEM_ID"));
} 
System.out.println(List3);
```

---

i get the u from

```
for (int u = 2; u < List1.size(); u++) {
  System.out.println(List1.get(u)); 
 }
```

it return me a int

========================================================================

but i encounter this error Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

is there any solution to this?

thanks!

Comment: Before post question. format it properly.

Comment: Where is your `List1`?

Comment: ohh i miss that out. is here srs = stmt
    .executeQuery("SELECT [USER_ID] FROM [USER_LITE].[USERS] WHERE ALLOW_LOGIN = 1");
  while (srs.next()) {
   List1.add(srs.getString("USER_ID"));

  }
  System.out.println(List1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Implicit conversion from datatype 
'VARCHAR' to 'NUMERIC' is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run
 this query.
```